# Find bijective linear function between sets of matrices & functions

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, elementary-set-theory

I know there are other questions on this topic, but none of them seemed to fit what I'm trying to do. However, that may just be my own limited understanding of the topic.

Given a set of m x n matrices and a set of functions with the domain of S, how can I find a bijective linear function between them?
For example, finding a function $F^{2x2} \to F^{\{1,2,3,4\}}$.

So far I've found plenty of literature on how to find a function between two established sets, but none involving matrices or sets of functions, so I'd really appreciate any advice.

Comment: If you're going to downvote, can you please explain how I can improve my question?

Comment: I haven't down voted. Here are some general advices: You should add more details. Which kind of matrices are you talking about? What is $S$? What should be the codomain? And finally what have you tired?

Comment: I was trying to be less specific so this could apply to more people's situations, but I suppose that backfired. I'll update as best as I can, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to specify a $2\times 2$ matrix, you need to name $4$ elements of $F$: the $4$ entries of the matrix.  And to specify a function $f:\{1,2,3,4\}\to F$, you also need to name $4$ elements of $F$: the values $f(1)$, $f(2)$, $f(3)$, and $f(4)$ of the function.  Furthermore, addition and scalar multiplication in both cases corresponds to just addition and scalar multiplication of each of the $4$ elements of $F$ separately.  So to get a linear bijection, you just turn the matrix entries into the values of the function.  Explicitly, you can define $B:F^{2\times 2}\to F^{\{1,2,3,4\}}$ by saying that $B\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$ is the function $f$ given by $f(1)=a$, $f(2)=b$, $f(3)=c$, and $f(4)=d$.  I'll leave it to you to prove that this really is a linear bijection.